# Search Bar for suitable site

Tags: feature-request, search

Sometimes when I'm using SE I need to post a question but I don't know which site to post it on.

I know there's a list of sites but the page on https://stackexchange.com/sites is quite hard to search and is a bit of a visual overload.

I was thinking that there could be a search bar where one could type a keyword and the 5 most suitable sites for that keyword would appear. Or maybe a review queue page where you can post your question and then a moderator/someone with enough rep can direct/post your question to the right site.

Comment: so you type apple and we suggest cookery or computing?

Comment: @RobertLongson Yeah, something like that! Or "book" and writers, ELL and ELU come up

Comment: Better use SEDE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287907/158100

Comment: @rene I'm looking at it but I don't quite understand it. Am i right in saying that you can use it to see all the sites that have a question/answer containing a given word??

Comment: No, just if a key word exist in its tag or tag wiki

Comment: Searching across all sites already exists: https://stackexchange.com/search?q=test

Comment: @rene Thanks but I was looking for a way to identify which site a question would go in....

Comment: No, because such a search bar would become the whipping-boy for every off-topic post anwhere: 'Your Q is hopelessly off-topic on our cider-brewers website - why ask about your tablet on here?'....'SO directed me here!   It's their fault!'

Comment: @MartinJames Perhaps something like a review page where you can ask your question and then a moderator/someone with enough rep directs your question to the right site??

Comment: The first rule of Site Club is: You do not talk about Site Club.

Comment: @AdiC no!   That would put up a name/account to blame for off-topic posts, rather than just SO in general.   Also, I don't know how those searching for sites and directing questions would get paid.  Obviously, nobody would do such work for free.

Comment: @MartinJames People would do it for the same reason as they do the other review queues in triage. It would just be another review queue. Also, there could be some sort of disclaimer saying that it's a recommendation/suggestion but the poster has ultimate responsibility.

Comment: ..because I can guarantee that, if some stup... misguided user did offer to direct questions for free, a better-advertized paysite that just redirects questions their way would spring up in milliseconds.

Comment: @AdiC no.  It's just slavery.  Working at an uninteresting, miserable site-search for no wages.  Nobody would touch such a pile of PHP with a bargepole.

Comment: @MartinJames I'm not saying this should be some sort of job!! Based on your rep, I'm assuming that you have done some reviews from the review queues in the past. All I'm saying is that it's just another queue (like the "First Posts" queue)

Comment: If your keyword is "book" why wouldn't Christianity.se, Islam.se and Money.se also come up? They also have things with books.

Comment: @rene Those were just the first few to come up in my mind

Comment: Your feature request is under specified then as it is unclear how a keyword should be mapped to a site.

Comment: @AdiC I try to stay away from the reviw queues; they are too depressing.  They give me bad dreams of loaded firearms, pill bottles, razor blades, tall buildings, railroad tracks and the like:(

Answer (score 6):

There is a site where you can ask where to ask. It's [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) it has a [site-recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag whose purpose is

> After looking through the site list, https://stackexchange.com/sites, you don't know where to ask your question on the Stack Exchange Network? Give as much detail as possible about the question you'd like to ask, and the community will help you find the appropriate site.

So if you're really stuck and you've looked at likely sites but you still don't know you can ask a question there about where your question would go. Be careful to ask where your question should go and don't just state the question you want to ask and expect it to be migrated. If your question is suitable for a Stack Exchange site, you'll need to ask it on the appropriate site directly.

Not all questions have an appropriate site though. If you've asked your question and had it closed as too-broad or unclear, there's probably no alternative site where you can ask a broad or unclear question.

Answer (score 1):

When I am looking for a suitable site, I use the *Filtered Questions* page from the [Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/10748310/adi-c).  If you select:

> Just questions tagged with the [    ] tag

and type a tag name into the box, it will show suggestions.

After selecting a tag, if you then select:

> Just these sites [ ]

It will show the sites on which this tag exists.